# Trying to redirect from getStaticProps returns error during build

Tags: next.js

I'm currently trying to redirect inside of `getStaticProps` based on an API call which checks for a cookie. If the cookie is present, user is authenticated, which means no redirect, but if missing, redirect.

```
import React from "react";
import { GetStaticProps } from "next";

const Chat: React.FC = () => {
    return null;
};

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async ({ locale, defaultLocale }) => {
    const { authenticated } = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/api/auth").then(res => res.json());

    if (!authenticated) {
        return {
            redirect: {
                permanent: false,
                destination: "/user/login",
            },
        };
    }

    return {
        props: {
            defaultLocale,
            locale,
        },
    };
};

export default Chat;
```

This works fine during runtime, but on build, I get the following error:

> Error: `redirect` can not be returned from getStaticProps during prerendering (/chat)

How so? [The official next.js doc even shows how to redirect from getStaticProps.](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation) [I even added the redirect to next.config.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects), but somehow it still fails.

```
module.exports = {
    async redirects() {
        return [
            {
                source: "/chat", 
                destination: "/user/login",
                permanent: false,
            },
        ];
    },
    ...
}
```

FYI the application uses `i18n` to danle translations, locales etc.

Comment: [`getStaticProps` runs at build-time](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#only-runs-at-build-time), you won't be able to access cookies nor user-specific data in it. You'd want to use `getServerSideProps` for that, or do it on the client.

Comment: Did you happen to solve this issue yourself? We got the same problem here.

Comment: @chenz Redirects can't be pre-rendered on build. If you have a dynamic route you can remove paths that include redirects from the returned paths and either use fallback `"blocking"` or `true` to pre-render not already generated pages on demand - other than that you can't use redirects within `getStaticProps`. For non dynamic pages you can use the middleware to read cookies and redirect accordingly.